# In which namespace is Utils.ReadFile written?

Tags: c#

In which namespace is `Utils.ReadFile` written in the .NET framework?

If it is not there, what DLL I need to refer to?

My code is as follows:

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder(Utils.ReadFile(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Daybook.html"))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Utils.readFile` is a Java statement. There is no standard .NET method named `Utils.ReadFile`. Maybe it is in a custom library.

You could use `File.ReadAllText` though:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Daybook.html")))
```